# How to copy project from iphone to ipad using xcode 8?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, copy, xcode8

I write a iphone project (Objective C) in XCode 8. I create a new iPad project. I want to copy the iPhone project and paste the iPad project.

what should I do ?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't make the original project universal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a new app for iPad (and not a universal app):
1- Make a copy of your project forlder.
2- Open the new copy that will target iPad. Open The xcodeproj file and in Xcode, select your project from the left menu, then select your target. From Deployment Info change Device target from iPhone to iPad.

[image: It should be like this image]

3- Now, your project targets iPad. Don't forget to edit your storyboards (or XIB files) to fit to iPad's screen size.

4- If this answers what you wanted to do, please don't forget to accept it :)